# Remote validation in MVC dose not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Hi guys i am developing a website with MVC and for validation of register page i,m using of remote validation for email address and username i have problem remote it,s working fine for user name but for email address dose not work please help
thanks..`

```
[Remote("EmailAddressExist", "Validation", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage="not available")] 
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
[Remote("UserNameExist", "Validation", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "not available")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

this my controller`

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public JsonResult EmailAddressExist(string email)
    {
        return Json(!db.Members.Any(s => s.EmailAddress==email),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public JsonResult UserNameExist(string username)
    {
        return Json(!db.Members.Any(s=>s.UserName==username),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

Comment: The first one wont work because the method parameter does not match the property name - it needs to be `public JsonResult EmailAddressExist(string emailAddress)`

Comment: Thanaks it,s work.Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!